# Printing pdf file in java using PDFRenderer 0.9.1 library

Tags: java, pdf, printing

I am trying to printout receipts of 80mm width using this java code that uses the PDFRenderer library and to print in an Epson TM-T20 printer. I tested it with windows XPS print preview at it turned out okay, but when i give a print out in my physical epson printer, The printer out is so small that it is almost microscopic.

```
public static void printPdf2(String filename) throws IOException, PrinterException{

    // Create a PDFFile from a File reference
    File f = new File(filename);
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
    FileChannel fc = fis.getChannel();
    ByteBuffer bb = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, fc.size());
    PDFFile pdfFile = new PDFFile(bb); // Create PDF Print Page
    PDFPrintPage pages = new PDFPrintPage(pdfFile);

    fis.close();

    // Create Print Job
    PrinterJob pjob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    PageFormat pf = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob().defaultPage();
    pjob.setJobName(f.getName());
    Book book = new Book();
    book.append(pages, pf, pdfFile.getNumPages());
    pjob.setPageable(book);
    PrintRequestAttributeSet attr_set = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
    attr_set.add(MediaSizeName.ISO_A6);

    // Send print job to default printer
    pjob.print(attr_set);


}
```

The pdf file sent to this method is formatted beforehand, on top of that in  printRequestAttributeSet it's also mentioned to print in A6 format. I dont know what is causing it to print in a microscopic level.

Comment: Is that Epson a receipt printer?

Comment: yes@Fildor
i am testing with it for now, but the program may have to run with a different reciept printer.

Comment: I see. Isuspect A6 is not correct. Maybe you'll have to make this configurable.

Comment: I tried avoiding it altogether, but produced the same result. How do i make it configurable?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so found a better way to do the task which works for me. Here is the code:

```
//this is where the method gets called with these params
JPrintFile.printPdf3(FILE,"PDF Print Job");
```

The method to print the pdf file

```
public static void printPdf3 (String filePath, String jobName) throws IOException, PrinterException {

    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(filePath);
    byte[] pdfContent = new byte[fileInputStream.available()];
    fileInputStream.read(pdfContent, 0, fileInputStream.available());
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(pdfContent);

    final PDFFile pdfFile = new PDFFile(buffer);
    PDFPrintPage pages = new PDFPrintPage(pdfFile);
    PrinterJob printJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    PageFormat pageFormat = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob().defaultPage();
    printJob.setJobName(jobName);
    Book book = new Book();

    book.append(pages, pageFormat, pdfFile.getNumPages());
    printJob.setPageable(book);
    Paper paper = new Paper();

    //paper has a default size, but i changed the size and ImageableArea
    //for my specific needs
    paper.setSize(400, 600);
    paper.setImageableArea(0, 0, paper.getWidth()-20, paper.getHeight()-20);
    System.out.println(paper.getHeight());
    System.out.println(paper.getWidth());
    pageFormat.setPaper(paper);

    //using default printService here
    PrintService p=PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
    printJob.setPrintService(p);

    PrintRequestAttributeSet attr_set = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
    attr_set.add(MediaSizeName.ISO_A6);

    printJob.print(attr_set);
    fileInputStream.close();
}
```

To implement this, you will need PDFRenderer 0.9.1. Just download the .jar and add it to the build path of your project.